# MATLAB App Designer reset properties

Tags: matlab

I have defined a list of private properties in MATLAB App Designer which are initialized as follows:

```
properties (Access = private)
    prop1 = val1;
    prop2 = val2;
    ...
end
```

I would now like to have a function that resets them to the default values as defined above. Is there an way to do this automatically or do I have to reset them manually (which can lead to errors e.g. when more properties are added)?

Also, is there a way to loop over all the properties I've defined in this way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to blanket reset *only* the private properties, you can use [`metaclass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html) to access the attributes of your properties and adjust as necessary.

For example:

```
classdef SOcode < handle
    properties
        a
        b
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        c = -1
        d = -1
    end

    methods
        function self = SOcode()
        end

        function changeprivate(self)
            self.c = randi(5);
            self.d = randi(5);
        end

        function printprivate(self)
            fprintf('c = %d\nd = %d\n', self.c, self.d)
        end

        function resetprivate(self)
            tmp = metaclass(self);
            props = tmp.PropertyList;
            nprops = numel(props);

            for ii = 1:nprops
                if strcmp(props(ii).SetAccess, 'private')
                    self.(props(ii).Name) = props(ii).DefaultValue;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Provides the desired behavior:

```
>> test = SOcode;
>> test.changeprivate;
>> test.printprivate;
c = 1
d = 1
>> test.resetprivate;
>> test.printprivate;
c = -1
d = -1
```